# Pycurl is not recognized by PyCharm after pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycurl

I tried to install `pycurl` in my virtual environment so I ran the following command:

```
pip install -U pycurl
```

Yet after the install, Pycharm was still warning me that `pycurl` was not recognized.

When I look in my `site-package` folder I do have a `pycurl-7.43.0.1.dist-info` folder but no `pycurl` folder

Could you help me to get a clean install for `pycurl`?

Comment: Is it only `pycurl`, or is it not working for any packages? Does it work from the command line? Have you configured PyCharm to use the virtualenv you're installing `pycurl` in?

Comment: Hello Adoni. It is only concerning pycurl. I imported other modules like requests without any issue. Yes my virtual env seems properly setup. Waiting for Pycurl I will use requests but this issue is triggering me somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it is to do the following in PyCharm:

- Go to *Settings* (Ctrl + Alt + S)
- Go to *Project Interpreter*
- Click on the + button on the right of the panel
- Find `pycurl`
- Click on *Install Package*

The warning should disappear after that.

Comment: I tried but still nope, i'm going crazy to try to solve this problem.